# JavaScript shorten long line in best way

Tags: javascript

I write a condition and the line of the condition too long. i am trying to shorten line in best way.
this is my condition.

```
if (me == 'apple' && you || me =='orange' || me == 'mango' || me == 'peanut' || me == 'coconut' || me == 'papaya' || me == 'grief'){
    console.log('you some thing')
}
```

The longest line of the code are not look good. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Could you wrap your conditions in parentheses, so that we can see if the && or the || should be applied in what order.

Comment: && has higher precedence than ||

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When testing to see if a value matches one of a collection of values, put them in an array.

```
const fruits = [ 'orange', 'mango', etc ];
```

Then test to see if that value is in the array:

```
if (fruits.includes(me)) ...
```

You'll still need to include the first part of your chain of booleans since that isn't a simple set of ORs.

Answer (score 3):

```
const food = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'peanut', 'coconut', 'papaya', 'grief']
food.indexOf('apple') // 0
food.includes('apple') // true
```

You can use indexOf to check if it's in an array simply. indexOf returns the position but if it's -1 it means that item doesn't exist in the array

You are not limited to indexOf you can  also use includes which will return a boolean telling you if it exists in the array

Simplifying that in an if will result in:

In the end you still have to include && you but that should solve the case of manually checking if each variable is written

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is better than using array IMO since access time will be `O(1)`

```
let newMap = new Map ([['orange','orange']....])
```

and then use

```
if(newMap.has(me))
```

Answer (score 2):

All posible condition in array and use array [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to shorten conditions.

```js
var allFruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'peanut', 'coconut', 'papaya', 'grief'];
var you = true;
var me = 'orange';

if (allFruits.includes(me) && you){
    console.log('you some thing')
}

// Below code is the special condition where apple and you relation needs to maintain.
if ((allFruits.includes('me') && me === 'apple' && you) || (allFruits.includes(me) && me !== 'apple' && !you)){
    console.log('you some thing')
}
```